# Elements moves on resize

Tags: html, css, resize

Okey so when I shrink my chrome window the Nav and the Header moves with the rezising. I don´t want that. The Mainbox however stays in position? No idea why but great! I can´t really find the difference between the Nav class and the Mainbox one except the overflow: auto which didn´t help on the nav nor the header.

```
    .container {
    height: 800px;
    width: 1500px;

}
body {
margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
}

header
{
    top: 11px;
    width: 100%;


    }

    ol {
    list-style-type: upper-roman;

    }

    .sideIMG {
    position:fixed;
    top: 200px;
    left: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;


    }
    .sideIMGR {
    position:absolute;
    top: 200px;
    right: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;


    }
.mainBox
{
    background-color: #F0F0F0 ;
    height: 1050px;
    width: 700px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    overflow: auto;
    top: 310px;

    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    }
.textBox
{   
height: 110px;
width: 200px;
background-color:#E8E8E8;
border-style: double;
}
    H1{

    font-family:"Brush Script MT";
    }

footer
{
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;

    top: 1360px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: #F0F0F0 ;


    }
.container nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav 
{
    padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    width: 700px;
    height:40px;


    background-color: #F0F0F0;

    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;

}
a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px;

}

a:hover 
{
     color:#00A0C6; 
     text-decoration:none; 
     cursor:pointer;  
}
.bildRuta
{
    height: 350px;
    width: 250px;
    left: 500px;
    top: 350px;
    }


.mainBox a img {
    border: medium solid #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.underRubrik
{`enter code here`
    font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;

    }
```

HTML:

```
 <center><header><img src="Bilder/spegel.jpg"/></header></center>
```

Comment: provide lil bit html code as well but i guess problem is in defining width in percentage (in header)

Comment: Add html code in your main Question you can do this by edit your question